shell color not displaying for username and host even set the color
using gnome-terminal ( default ) and added below in ~/.bashrc to colorize the terminal
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
 46# force_color_prompt=yes
 47 
 48 if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
 49     if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
 50         # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
 51         # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
 52         # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
 53         color_prompt=yes
 54     else
 55         color_prompt=
 56     fi
 57 fi
 58 
 59 RED='\[\033[01;31m\]'
 60 YELLOW='\[\033[01;33m\]'
 61 GREEN='\[\033[01;32m\]'
 62 BLUE='\[\033[01;34m\]'
 63 
 64 CYAN='\[\033[01;36m\]'
 65 LIGHT_CYAN='\[\033[00;36m\]'
 66 WHITE='\[\033[00m\]'
 67 LIGHT_GRAY='\[\033[01;37m\]'
 68 COLOR_NONE='\[\e[00m\]'
 69 
 70 
 71 parse_git_branch () {
 72    while read -r branch; do
 73         [[ $branch = \** ]] && current_branch=${branch#* }
 74    done < <(git branch 2>/dev/null)
 75    [[ $current_branch ]] && printf '(%s)' "$current_branch"
 76 }
 77 
 78 
 79 if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 80 #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00m\]\t \[\033[01;37m\]\u@\[\033[01;36m\]\h\[\033[01;33m\]:\[\033[00;32m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\] $(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
 81 PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)} \\[$(tput setaf 2)\\]\t ${LIGHT_GRAY}\u@\h${GREEN}:${BLUE}\w${RED} $(parse_git_branch)${WHITE}$ "
 82 else
 83 PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\t${LIGHT_GRAY}\u@\h${GREEN}:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ "
 84 fi
 85 PS1="$PS1${RED}"
 86 
 87 unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

but it does not who host and username diffrent color as defined while dir and command are colored as defined
what could be the issue here?
Note: if comment line # 87 unset color-prompt forced-color-prompt then branches name are not getting dispalyed in shell
see the attached screenshot below

so How can we enable the color for the host/username also?

Undo the addtions you made to line #83, leaving in just the git branch name; this is the prompt that is meant to be shown in case the terminal has no color support:
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)} \t \u@\h:\w \$(parse_git_branch)\$ "

Then set your color prompt in line #81; for the purpose of the example, I'm setting the username to yellow, the @ to white and the hostname to cyan (I will use ${GREEN} instead of \\[$(tput setaf 2)\\] to mantain consistency with the rest of the prompt):
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)} ${GREEN}\t ${YELLOW}\u${WHITE}@${CYAN}\h${GREEN}:${BLUE}\w ${RED}\$(parse_git_branch)${WHITE}\$ "

You may consider swapping ANSI color escape codes for tput commands to achieve better compatibility across different terminals on systems where tput is installed, at the cost of a slight overhead.


You should escape the $(parse_git_branch) so that it's evaluated each time the prompt is printed. Otherwise it'll be evaluated at the time PS1 is set, and won't change when you cd to a different git repo.

@muru Yup, that's what I get for copy-pasting stuff without checking / testing. Thanks

Thanks. it worked. adding tput was just to check diffrent approach to colorize the terminal, removed now.

@xkeshav You're welcome, by the way my tput inquiry was only because of the inconsistency between that and the raw ANSI color escape codes; one might argue that tput would grant a better compatibilty across different terminals (assuming that tput is installed on the system of course)
